# When trying to change command line, received an error: "Could not set command line!"

Tags: x64dbg, command-line

I download [CurrPort](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html) program and run it on xdbg64.

I pressed `File -> Changed Command line` and changed the command line to:

```
"C:\Users\myusername\Downloads\cport\cports.exe" "/close * * 127.0.0.1 6666"
```

But I received an error:
[image: an]

Why it happens and how to solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it happens, but let's try to debug it:

1. Run cmd.exe, type your command to there and press Enter - if it doesn't work, a problem in wrong path/args;
2. Run x64dbg, open your app, go to an editing command line and put there only one argument; Then go to Debug tab and press restart;
3. Also, you can try to set cmd-line initing step, like this:

   *x64_dgb "C:\FullPathTo\File.exe" parm1 parm2 -3 -4 -debug*

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this too, it's broke currently. Event if you pass the command line like slinkin says, only part of it will show up.
I went back to an older 8/9/2019 for now and it works fine.